# Dynamic key with paramaters in Typescript

Tags: typescript, object, dynamic, key

I have an object like this

```
const SUMs = {
sum_1: {},
sum_2:{},
sum_3:{},
sum_4:{}
}
```

Now I want to access it through a loop range like this

```
for (let i of [1,2,3,4]){
 const key = `sum_${i}`
 const sum = SUMs[key]
}
```

but it's not working, so any solution that can help me in this context?
Thanks!

Comment: How is it not working? Any error messages?

Comment: @VLAZ "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type" this is the error messages

Comment: @ThanhHải, consider adding a type annotation to `SUMs` as a hint to the compiler that what you're doing is okay (e.g. `const SUMs: { [key: string]: {} } = ...`).

Comment: @miqh nice, it works, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways around this:

1. Wide the type for `SUMS`

Typescript infers the type of `SUMS` if you don't provide an annotation as:

```js
{
    sum_1: {};
    sum_2: {};
    sum_3: {};
    sum_4: {};
}
```

You can instead widen this type to `{[key: string]: {}}`, and this will allow you to access items in here using `SUMs[string]`

2. You can instead type assert your key like so:

```js
for (let i of [1, 2, 3, 4]) {
  const key = `sum_${i}`;
  const sum = SUMs[key as keyof typeof SUMs]; // you're asserting that `key` can only be keys of the `SUMs` object

  console.log(sum);
}
```

Arguably (2) is a more correct approach